# How do I actually catch an exception triggered by an NGXS dispatch?

Tags: angular, exception, ngxs

Our project has a system that displays an error modal to the user if an unhandled exception makes its way to the root. (If it matters, this sits in `providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: OurHandler}]` in `AppModule`’s `@NgModule`, where `OurHandler`’s `handleError` displays the appropriate modal.)

Catching an exception prevents the modal—usually. But for some reason, nothing I do seems to actually catch the exception in the case of an NGXS dispatch.

Some code that works, for background:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class ApiService {

  constructor (private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  doTheThing(params: Foo): Promise<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(aUrl, params).toPromise();
  }
}

@State<ThingDoingModel>({ name: 'doing' }) // there's also some defaults here
@Injectable()
export class ThingDoingState {

  constructor (private readonly apiService: ApiService) {}

  @Action(DoTheThing)
  doTheThing(ctx: StateContext<ThingDoingModel>, { foo }: DoTheThing): Promise<string> {
    return this.apiService.doTheThing(foo);
  }
}

@Component({ /*…*/ })
class ThingComponent {

  constructor (private readonly store: Store) {}

  onSubmit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new DoTheThing(this.foo)).subscribe(() => {
      this.showSuccessModal();
    });
  }
}
```

This all works perfectly—so long as doing the thing is successful. However, sometimes the POST might get an error response. So I want to catch that, and call `this.showErrorModal(error.message)`. That isn’t hard either—but no matter what I do, the exception keeps bubbling up so I *also* get our default unhandled error modal.

Things I’ve tried:

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new DoTheThing(this.foo))
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          this.showErrorModal(err.message);
          return EMPTY;
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.showSuccessModal();
      });
  }
```

```js
  onSubmit() {
    try {
      this.store.dispatch(new DoTheThing(this.foo)).subscribe(() => {
        this.showSuccessModal();
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      this.showErrorModal(err.message);
    }
  }
```

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new DoTheThing(this.foo)).toPromise()
      .then(() => {
        this.showSuccessModal();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.showErrorModal(err.message);
      });
  }
```

But none of these actually catch the exception thrown when the `HttpClient` gets a 500 response. They mostly work—the actual `try`/`catch` version didn’t display the error modal I wanted, but the others did—but in all of these I also get the second modal that I do not want.

So how and/or where do I actually catch this exception?

Comment: If you return an `Observable<string>` instead of `Promise<string>` from your `apiService.doTheThing` and `doTheThing` action, then add a `pipe` and `catchError` within the `doTheThing` action (not in the component), then let us know if the error is catched there or not, please.

Comment: @Amer Yes, catching it there does work. But that does me limited good since I can’t display the modal there. Do I really have to catch there, construct my own error object to return as a not-error, and then discriminate between an error and a successful response in my `.subscribe`?

Comment: @Amer Actually, that doesn’t even seem to work: whatever I return from `catchError` in the action, doesn’t seem to be the argument that I get in `dispatch(/*…*/).subscribe(arg`. So that helps, sort of, but I’m not seeing a route to solving my problem through that.

Comment: Actually, your 1st and 3rd tries should work, even if you don't use `catchError` in your action. Could you please provide a minimal reproducible StackBlitz? I usually handle it the same way without any problem.